# How to reload my gunicorn server automatically?

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I want to know, how to restart my gunicorn server automatically. after my django project code has been changed. currently now i am doing manual restart after i made changes , just kill the process and reload it. but it is not a good way. so i want to know how to do the same automatically after code getting changed . i am using nginx too.

Comment: Use gunicorn for production only. For development, use Django's server.

Comment: Use the `--reload` argument.

Comment: That depends on how you actually run your gunicorn...

Comment: i am using gunicorn for my production alone. for development i am using local django wsgi only...

Comment: I am running gunicorn like this ,  gunicorn_django -b 127.0.0.1:8000 -w3 -p /tmp/gunicorn_appname.pid

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the reload setting:

https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#debugging

> reload
>
> --reload False Restart workers when code changes.
>
> This setting is intended for development. It will cause workers to be
>   restarted whenever application code changes.